# Mutating a variable depending on year using r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to standardized a variable by a national average depending on the year to create a new variable that is a Z score. Here is an example dataset:

```
 DF:
 Var1   Var2
 240     2015
 210     2018
 206     2016
 248     2017
 235     2019
----etc
```

I am using the following code:

```
DF$NewZScore<- if (DF$Var2== "2015"){
  (DF$Var1 - 229)/20
} else if (DF$Var2== "2016"){
  ((DF$Var1 - 228)/21
  } else if (DF$Var2== "2017"){
  ((DF$Var1 - 229)/20
    } else if (DF$Var2== "2018"){
  ((DF$Var1 - 230)/19
  } else if (DF$Var2== "2019"){
  ((DF$Var1 - 231)/19
} else {
  + 1000
}
```

The years 2015 through 2019 are the years I am wanting, there are a few other years which I will filter out after (thus, the + 1000). This code is mutating Var1 by the 2015 criteria rather than mutating the variable by the year in Var2. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `dplyr`, there you can use `case_when`. Also, I recommend to use `NA` for the entries where you don't want to have a z score:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text = " Var1   Var2
 240     2015
 210     2018
 206     2016
 248     2017
 235     2019", header = TRUE)

df_new <- df %>% 
  filter(Var2 >= 2015 & Var2 <= 2019) %>% 
  mutate(NewZScore = case_when(
    Var2 == 2015 ~ (Var1 - 229)/20,
    Var2 == 2016 ~ (Var1 - 228)/21,
    Var2 == 2017 ~ (Var1 - 229)/20,
    Var2 == 2018 ~ (Var1 - 230)/19,
    Var2 == 2019 ~ (Var1 - 231)/19,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))

df_new
  Var1 Var2  NewZScore
1  240 2015  0.5500000
2  210 2018 -1.0526316
3  206 2016 -1.0476190
4  248 2017  0.9500000
5  235 2019  0.2105263
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer answers your question, please consider to accept it.

Comment: While this does what I want it to do, it seems to have made this variable a tibble within my dataframe. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: A tibble is just an additional class added by `dplyr`, it still also has the class `data.frame` and (mostly) behaves like it. You find more information [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html). Otherwise, you can just use `as.data.frame`